# Excel formula with if condition

Tags: excel

I have this excel formula, and I'm not used to work with excel, I can't understand what this formula mean, can any one make it clear?

[excel formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Q9sDW.png)

Comment: what did you try? add some code

Comment: https://support.office.com/fr-fr/article/fonction-somme-si-169b8c99-c05c-4483-a712-1697a653039b

Comment: =+SOMME.SI('Réal comm au 31-03-2018'!$B:$B;B36;'Réal comm au 31-03-2018'!$X:$X)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The workbook has a sheet called **'Réal comm au 31-03-2018'** this is not necessarily the same where the function is defined.

you have 2 ranges that are:
 **'Réal comm au 31-03-2018'!$B:$B** (column B inside 'Réal comm au 31-03-2018') 
 **'Réal comm au 31-03-2018'!$X:$X** (column X inside 'Réal comm au 31-03-2018')

**B36** is on the same sheet as the formula.
The function will iterate the cells of the range in column B, when the value in the current cell is equal to the value in cell B36 it
will sum the value in column X of the same cell.

I hope this can helps you :)

Comment: Thank you :D that's helpful

Answer (score 0):

it said that there are sheet on this workbook named 'Réal comm au 31-03-2018'
and the maker of this file using a special function named SOMME.SI
that do some thing special between the to columns B   &   X depending on the value of the cell B36